# Fetch or clone data from input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am currently having some issues with the following script:

```
    <input name="MYNEWVALUE" class="MYNEWVALUE" maxlength="20" type="text" id="MYNEWVALUE">
    <a onclick="addURL(this)" href="<?php echo $escaped_url?>">Click this</a>
    
    <script>
    function addURL(element)
    {
        $(element).attr('href', function() {
            return this.href + '?notes=...';
        });
    }
    </script>
```

As you can see I have an input field which I called MYNEWVALUE and a Button with a Javascript function. This button once clicked adds a specific parameter to my URL e.g. **https://myurl.com/?notes=...**

What I am currently trying to achieve is to fetch the data from the input field (as soon as the Button has been clicked) and use it or clone it directly in conjunction to this.href + '?notes=**MYNEWVALUE**';

So If I would enter **Testing** the final URL to be passed on should become **https://myurl.com/?notes=Testing**

Is there a way to intercept or clone this value? Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Sounds like what you're doing in JS is the default behavior of an HTML `<form method=get>`, you might want to give it a try if you wish your page to be supported even when JS is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is change how you're handling the event handling and simplify it like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo $escaped_url?>" id="button">Click this</a>

<script>
    $("#button").on("click", function() {
        this.href += "?notes=" + $("#MYNEWVALUE").val();
    });
</script>
```

[jQuery `.click()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/) as follows (note you cannot use an ES6 function for this one due to the ES6 arrow function's lexical `this`).

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much for your help, it worked right out of the box! Thanks again